# "Magic constructor" in Ruby for all attributes

Tags: ruby, dry, shortcut

Is there a way to set a default initialize method without writing it down?

```
class DataClass
  attr_accessor :title, :description, :childs
  def hasChilds?
    @childs.nil?
  end
end
```

I Want to initialize this class with standard initial attributes. Something like this:

```
$> a = DataClass.new(:title => "adsf", :description => "test")
$> a.title # --> "asdf"
```

Is there such a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you might be able to use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/OpenStruct.html)

```
a = OpenStruct.new(:title => "adsf", :description => "test")
>> a.title
=>> "adsf"
```

Comment: Ah, great! Thats what I am searching for!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: with `OpenStruct` there is no runtime error checking if you try to reference an attribute that wasn't set in the constructor. `OpenStruct` is effectively a glorified hash. Access an unknown attribute and you get a `nil` response.

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use a `Struct` as the base of your class.  For example:

```
class DataClass < Struct.new(:title, :description, :childs)
  def has_childs?
    @childs.nil?
  end
end

a = DataClass.new('adsf', 'description')
puts a.title
```

Now the order of the parameters is important.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the constructor gem does exactly what you want:
http://atomicobject.github.com/constructor/

```
  require 'constructor'

  class Horse
    constructor :name, :breed, :weight
  end
  Horse.new :name => 'Ed', :breed => 'Mustang', :weight => 342
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this gem](http://rbjl.net/32-introducing-ruby-zucker-a-new-syntactical-sugar-gem) and then simply do:

```
require 'zucker/ivars'

def initialize(variable1, variable2)
  instance_variables_from binding # assigns @variable1 and @variable2
end
```

The "zucker" gem also allows you to use a hash! Have a look at the [example](http://rbjl.net/32/ivars_example.rb).

Comment: Nice gem, thanks! But I dont want to introduce another gem in my project for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

[Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) works great for this.

```
horse = Hashie::Mash.new(name: 'Ed', breed: 'Mustang', weight: 342)
horse.name    # 'Ed'
horse[:name]  # 'Ed'
horse['name'] # 'Ed'
```

You can also its Dash class to make a real class with restricted attribute names. And a bunch of other useful data structures too.